# Real Solution basis of $y'+y = x^2\cos x$ using annihilator method

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Ineed to find a real Solution basis of solution space of $y'+y = x^2\cos x$ using annihilator method. My attempt: I know that the annihilator of $x^2\cos x$ is $(D^{2} + I)^3$. Then we have $(D^2+I)^3(D+I) = 0$. The eigenvalue of $(D+I)^3$ is $i,-i$, each of mutlipilicity $3$. Then the complex vectoro basis of solution space of this equation is $\{e^{ix}, xe^{ix}, x^2e^{ix}, e^{-ix}, xe^{-ix}, x^2e^{-ix}\}$. Then we need to change the complex basis to real basis. We know that $e^{ix} = \sin x + i \cos x$. Then we have $\frac{\cos x + i\sin x +\cos x - i \sin x}{2} = \cos x$, $\frac{\cos x + i \sin x - (\cos x -i\sin x )}{2i} = \sin x$, $\frac{x(\cos x + i \sin x ) + x(\cos x - i \sin x )}{2} = x\cos x$, $\frac{x(\cos x + i \sin x) - x(\cos x - i\sin x)}{2i} = x \sin x$, $\frac{x^2(\cos x + i\sin x) + x^2 (\cos x -i\sin x)}{2} = x^2 \cos x$, $\frac{x^2 (\cos x + i \sin x) - x^2 (\cos x -i\sin x)}{2i} = x^2 \sin x$. Then the real basis has $\cos x, \sin x, x\cos x, x \sin x, x^2 \cos x, x^2\sin x, f(x), g(x)$. However, there are eight components in total. However, I think that there are only seven of them. Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my solution.

Comment: That's making it much harder.  $D^2+I$ annihilates $\cos x$ without the third power.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry I've typed my problem wrong. It should be $x^2 \cos x$

Comment: All right.  What are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ then?  You only get to eight with them included.